# Deploy times out Elasticbeanstalk after introducing load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing

I have a working Golang API deployed to AWS Elasticbeanstalk

All worked fine until I setup Application load balancer and started using https and custom domain.

Now I cannot deploy anything, it fails with message

```
The following instances have not responded in the allowed command timeout time (they might still finish eventually on their own): [i-...].
```

And it reverts back to previous version

I created custom domain on Route53 <mysite.com> and subomain api.mysite.com (used for this API). Records and certificates are successfully setup and I can ping using both http and https. / route works just fine

Below is configuration on my LB:

instances min 1 max 2

[image]

[image]

Target groups:

[image]

I have no idea why health checks on port 80 fails,  when I try accessing browser it works just fine

I do not see anything in logs, expect of /var/logs/nginx/error.log, I can see a bunch of errors:

```
2023/12/13 09:25:28 [error] 3173#3173: *173053 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.33.242, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.47.51"
```

And these errors are even there after reverting to previous version

Can it be related to bad health check setup? Maybe I should extend an interval and number of checks? Can I do anything to further debug this?

Thanks in advance